# SQL LIKE clause not returning proper calues

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL, so despite searching here and on the Web i haven't been able to figure out my issue. I need to select the products that are tables or desks and that cost more than $300, everything else is correct, but I'm returning all dollar amounts, not just those more than $300.

here is the statement

```
SELECT ProductDescription, ProductFinish, ProductStandardPrice 
FROM product_t WHERE ProductDescription LIKE '%table%' OR ProductDescription LIKE '%desk%' 
AND ProductStandardPrice > 300;
```

Comment: `WHERE (ProductDescription LIKE '%table%' OR ProductDescription LIKE '%desk%') 
AND ProductStandardPrice > 300`

Comment: you are missing braces on or pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite your formatting, [operator precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html) means your query is interpreted like this:

```
SELECT ProductDescription, ProductFinish, ProductStandardPrice 
FROM product_t WHERE ProductDescription LIKE '%table%'
OR (ProductDescription LIKE '%desk%' AND ProductStandardPrice > 300);
```

If a product description contains "table", it will be returned regardless of the price. To always check the price, just insert the parentheses appropriately:

```
SELECT ProductDescription, ProductFinish, ProductStandardPrice 
FROM product_t WHERE (ProductDescription LIKE '%table%' OR ProductDescription LIKE '%desk%')
AND ProductStandardPrice > 300;
```

Comment: @l.bol If this solved your problem, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/304954) the answer.